# ISO 14443a Card Will Not Connect - Strange Error Code

Tags: nfc, iso

I am getting a strange output when I try to connect my ISO 14443a card to an NFC reader.

- 0:    :     26
- 0:   0: TAG 04  00
- 0:    :     93  20
- 0:   0: TAG 47  82  db  b3  ad
- 0:    :     93  70  47  82  db  b3  ad  3a  f4
- 0:   0: TAG 28  b4  fc
- 0:    :     e0  50  bc  a5
- 0:   0: TAG 13  78  80  82  02  80  31  80  66  b0  84  16  01  6e  01  83  00  90  00  03  d1
- 0:    :     e0  50  bc  a5
- 0:   0: TAG 13  78  80  82  02  80  31  80  66  b0  84  16  01  6e  01  83  00  90  00  03  d1
- 0:    :     c2  e0  b4      **<<<< WHAT??**
- 0:   0: TAG 03  6a  82  4f  75
- 0:    :     26
- 0:   0: TAG 04  00
- 0:    :     78

You can see that the cards is woken up, performs the anti-collision, then sends its ATS when requested (it gets asked twice for some reason?).

After this, the reader sends a strange command (marked above) and the card responds with an 'Operation not supported' response.

The wake-up, anti-collision protocol then restarts, and this goes on and on.

My question is, what does the command (**c2 e0 b4**) sent from the reader mean?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you are still interested in the response, I will just save time for anyone else who might be looking for the solution(like I was).

This is nothing else but ***S(Deselect)*** block sent from the reader, consisting of Protcol Contol Byte(PCB) and 2 bytes of CRC_A

**C2 E0 B4**

The same applies for anyone who might be looking for this command coming from the reader:

**B2 67 C7**

It is ***R(NACK)*** block, consisting of Protcol Contol Byte(PCB) and 2 bytes of CRC_A

They both are a fundamental part of ISO-DEP protocol(Type 4A or Type 4B tags), so read description and how to properly handle them in the "NFC Digital Protocol" spec, chapter "13 ISO-DEP Protocol"